# Way to extract a portion of a path from a URL using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Any way to extract just a portion of a full path from a URL using JavaScript?

Example:
I have URL
http://www.somedomain.com/account/6099bb4e2eb24bab85e8b76851a14260/search?filter=a#top

but I would just like to get this portion
`6099bb4e2eb24bab85e8b76851a14260`

This is a random id
few examples like:

```
6099bb4e2eb24bab85e8b76851a14260,
93b04efd1a734407b28f95d9c5278c0f,
94c9483fdb3747b38e4836fe9294cbfe,
93b04efd1a734407b28f95d9c5278c0f
```

Please help me out...its driving me nutts.
Learning....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go about doing it like this,

```
const url=new URL('http://www.somedomain.com/account/6099bb4e2eb24bab85e8b76851a14260/search?filter=a#top');

/*
url.pathname="/account/6099bb4e2eb24bab85e8b76851a14260/search"
url.pathname.split('/')=["","account","6099bb4e2eb24bab85e8b76851a14260","search"]
*/
const accountId=url.pathname.split('/')[2];
console.log(accountId);
```

Refer this for more on how to use the `URL` object in JS,
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL

Answer (score 0):

This should get you the desired result.

```
function myFunction() {
  var url = "http://www.somedomain.com/account/6099bb4e2eb24bab85e8b76851a14260/search?filter=a#top";
  var result = str.split('/')[4];
  console.log(result);
}
```

This is a simple example of splitting the url string and selecting the position of the desired value